# Automatic metadata capture

Tags: metadata

In SharePoint 2010, can I automatically capture the file properties of office document in document library or list? For example, when I'm uploading a excel sheet into document library, the values like Date created, modified, author etc should be updated in SharePoint columns.

Comment: Where would this metadata come from that you are populating a list item with? There are already system columns for Created, Created By, Modified date, etc..

Comment: SharePoint already maps some relevant metadata to the appropriate columns. Take a look at the document information panel in Word. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447589(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: in my test, these metainfo are updated by sharepoint not you.